# How do I import a csv through Web SQL API in an node webkit app?

Tags: web-sql, node-webkit

I'm creating a database using Web SQL APi in node webkit using this :

```
var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'my first database', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
```

How do I import a csv into a table in myDb?

Thanks.